# Appending Javascript Array Values to the DOJO div

Tags: javascript, dojox.charting

I have a Array of Values as shown above .

```
myarray2.push("10-FEB-11");
myarray2.push("11-FEB-11");
myarray2.push("12-FEB-11");
myarray2.push("13-FEB-11");
myarray2.push("14-FEB-11");
```

I want to have these Values inside the div hrXAxisSlider as shown  (Currently its hardcoded , but is that possible )

```
  <div id="hrXAxisSlider"
  dojoType="dojox.form.HorizontalRangeSlider">


   <ol dojoType="dijit.form.HorizontalRuleLabels" >
     <li>10-FEB-11</li><li>11-FEB-11</li><li>12-FEB-11</li><li>13-FEB-11</li><li>14-FEB-11</li>
   </ol>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a simple javascript for loop:

```
var ol = document.getElementById('hrXAxisSlider')
                 .getElementsByTagName('ol')[0],
    ma2l = myarray2.length,
    i, 
    htmlFrag = '';

for (i = 0; i < ma2l; i++) {
    htmlFrag += '<li>' + myarray2[i] + '</li>';
}

ol.innerHTML = htmlFrag;
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/adkGf/)