# Appending to the Dojo DIV

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Appending Javascript Array Values to the DOJO div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450913/appending-javascript-array-values-to-the-dojo-div)

Hi ,

I have Array of values as shown :

var myarray2 = [];

```
myarray2.push("10-FEB-11");
myarray2.push("11-FEB-11");
myarray2.push("12-FEB-11");
myarray2.push("13-FEB-11");
myarray2.push("14-FEB-11");
myarray2.push("15-FEB-11");
```

I am trying to append it to the DIV , but Data is coming upto Alert , but not getting displayed using innerHtml property , Please help

```
 var ol = document.getElementById('hrXAxisSlider').getElementsByTagName('ol');

   var i;
   var  htmlFrag = '';

   for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    htmlFrag += '<li>' + myarray2[i] + '</li>';
     }
   alert(htmlFrag);
 ol.innerHTML = htmlFrag.value;
```

Comment: I already answered this for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450913/appending-javascript-array-values-to-the-dojo-div/5450983#5450983 You should add comments to that question instead of starting a duplicate one.

Comment: @user663724, that's right.  Why are you wasting people's time asking a totally equivalent question, while changing @mVChr's previous answer into a version that doesn't work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modify your code slightly, as follows, i am given sample code.

function start(){
var myarray2 = [];

myarray2.push("10-FEB-11");
myarray2.push("11-FEB-11");
myarray2.push("12-FEB-11");
myarray2.push("13-FEB-11");
myarray2.push("14-FEB-11");
myarray2.push("15-FEB-11");

 var ol = document.getElementById('hrXAxisSlider');

   var i;
   var  htmlFrag = '';
   htmlFrag="

  ";

     for (i = 0; i ' + myarray2[i] + '
  ';
       }
       htmlFrag+="

"
   alert(htmlFrag);
 ol.innerHTML = htmlFrag;

}

in body part give one DIV and id is "hrXAxisSlider"

1. one
2. one

i am given div content is sample

if u provide u r mail id i will send complete code

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` return a NodeList.  It does *NOT* return a single node.

You have to do: `getElementsByTagName("ol")[0]` to get the first `ol` node.